# After call a php function by ajax how to apply its result for to check another submission

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

If user not banned, user can comment here. So I have a php function to check banned user. In case of comment form submitting, a ajax call 1st check this user is banned or not. If not: comment will be submit else display a massage.

Here, I cannot submit any comment if banned or not, Page refresh if I try to submit. In cannot also understand how to apply my `banneduser()` response to check form submitting.

php function: (I dont want change it, because I used it many more case)

```
//user name banned by user
function Banned($user){
global $db;
  if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
     $touser = addslashes($user);
  }
  $byuser = $_SESSION['user'];
  $result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM blocking WHERE byname = '$byuser' AND toname = '$touser'") or die(mysqli_error($db));
  return (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0);
}
```

Ajax:

```
// check banned user
function banneduser(){
var Bauthor = $("#author").attr("value");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "../common", 
        data: "action=Banned&user="+ Bauthor,
        success: function(data){
            // How to play with this data
            if(data){
            return false;
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
}

//comment submit if user not banned
$(".reply").on("click",function(){
    if(banneduser()){
         // make form submission
    } else { // You are banned}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AJAX request is asynchronous which means the rest of the code (i.e. the `return false` will execute before the response is processed. This means that `banneduser()` will always return `false`.

What you should do is pass a callback function to `banneduser` which is then executed once the AJAX response is received:

```
function banneduser(callback){
var Bauthor = $("#author").attr("value");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: "../common", 
        data: "action=Banned&user="+ Bauthor,
        success: function(data){

          callback(data)

        }
    });
    return false;
}

//comment submit if user not banned
$(".reply").on("click",function()
{

    banneduser(function (is_banned)
    {

      if (is_banned)
      {
        // You are banned
      }

      else
      {
        // Submit form
      }

    }
    )

});
```

Although, this script is easily hacked. It's trivial for a visitor (who know what he's doing) to change the value of `#author` until he finds a value that works. You should use a purely server-side solution to the problem (i.e. a session variable which stores the author value).

Comment: Thank you. I am using a  server-side solution now.